# Group several nodes for action and be notificated after completion

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, grouping, skaction

I have a SKNode with some children. For these children I'd like to apply actions which should start a the same time (sample code, k1000ms is a constant):

```
let children = self.children        
for var i=0; i<children.count; i++ {
  children[i].runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.), duration: k1000ms))
}
```

The point I don't know how long an iteration takes so starting actions for a huge number of children might result in a delay between the first and last started action.
The solution is obviously apply the actions to all nodes first and then starting the actions with a single call (hopefully the OS takes care of proper synchronization but this is an other issue).

Question 1: How to apply the actions to all nodes first and afterwards start all at once?

Question 2: How to get notified all actions are performed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: You can't and needn't. All actions started (run) in the same frame with the same duration will end in the same frame. Your entire for loop is performed in a single frame (unless you are multithreading it). [The next frame won't process (evaluate) actions and render until your for loop has ended.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043)

[image]

2: Use a [sequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:) action with a [runblock](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock:) action as the last action, or use the [completion block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:completion:).

Comment: Yes, should have read this more carefully, found a solution which hopefully lasts. One question remains: how does the framework knows when my code finished adding actions to the nodes?

Comment: it doesn't know, it just runs the scene' update which runs your code and that (hopefully) finishes eventually. It's a normal sequential flow of execution.